# Validate HTML input fields and redirect with JavaScript to web links

Tags: javascript, html

I created a text/input field and a button. When I click on the button it must check the input text and validate it to see which website it should redirect to, but it's not working:

**HTML**:

```
<input id="webNo" class="form-control">
<a onclick="redirectTo()" id="link_ref">Find</a>
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function redirectTo(){

    var trackingNo = document.getElementById('webNo').value;

    if (nameField.startsWiths("RW")){ 
 document.getElementById("link_ref").location.href="https://www.website1.com";
    } 
    else if (nameField.startsWiths("SUB") {

document.getElementById("link_ref").location.href="https://www.website2.com";}
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What you've posted is more of a job brief. You need to show some code and effort, then tell us what's not working, and we can help out.

Comment: Simple. Learn to access the html values in javascript and string manipulation in js.

Comment: Please edit the question and give us some nice, formatted code rather than using comments for that.

Comment: @Utkanos, thanks, will do - obviously new to this :(

Comment: No worries. Ultimately we're here to help. People give up their time to help for free, so it's important to try to format the question in the easiest way possible for people to digest it. The [How to Ask a Good Question article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is useful.

Comment: @Utkanos - I'll definitely have a read thank you! I've edited the post, hope this is a bit better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is

```js
function redirectTo() {
    var trackingNo = document.getElementById('webNo').value;
    var linkRef = document.getElementById("link_ref");
      
      if (trackingNo.startsWith("RW")) { 
          alert("you will be redirected to website1.com")

          linkRef.href="https://www.google.com";
      } else if (trackingNo.startsWith("SUB")) {
          alert("you will be redirected to website2.com")
          linkRef.location.href="https://www.youtube.com";
      }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="webNo" class="form-control">
<a onclick="redirectTo()" id="link_ref" href="#">Find</a>
```

- If you do the actual search, it will not work because the browser will block redirects in an `<iframe>`
- startsWith() is the name of the method
- You are doing the redirectTo() through a handler, so you must enclose it in a function as it triggers separately from the document (when you do `$(document).ready()` you are executing right after page load).
- Optimally, this should be in an anonymous function `(function())`
- You don't really need jQuery for this.
- `location.href` belongs to the window object.

Comment: Thank you @carkod! It works perfectly :) You made a tiny mistake in the code - the second linkRef should be `linkRef.href=` instead of `linkRef.location.href=`, but I changed it on my side. Thanks everyone for the help, truly appreciate it!

Comment: @Apprentice thanks! As you see all developers no matter how experienced will make mistakes.